# How to install Windows 8 Pro after installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 14.04, windows, system-installation

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 in my Lenovo G505s Laptop and now I also want to install Windows 8 Pro. I have already done an ntfs partition through gParted Partion Editor in ubuntu. This is the same partition where I want to install my Windows 8 Pro. I want to do a dual boot.

Please Help.

Comment: After booting to BIOS menu is there any option called "Secureboot"?

Comment: No there is not..

Comment: Then did you try to boot from window 8.1 dvd or pendrive?

Comment: And can you plese post a screenshot of your partition table?

Comment: But I am not able to create a partition for windows through gParted cause its not able to unmount my disk. What should I Do??

Answer (score 0):

As far I can remember, is better use Linux boot loader. so first install windows 8, then  linux, or install windows 8 now and do a grub2 tricky

I can't remember where, and the name of it option , but there is a legacy feature (at the bios) it comes to light curiously with windows 8 go into market
which prevent dual bot or install linux when windows 8 are hd master.

(Sorry i can't comment. so I post it)

Answer (score 0):

Windows has to be installed on a 1st partition of a disc. You can not create empty space randomly on your disc and install Windows in that (other operating systems do work like that).

Possible option besides reinstalling (and installing windows 1st and Ubuntu 2nd): you need to create space at the **beginning** of the disc. You can use the live dvd for this or a custom gparted live dvd.